# Where to apply for Multiple Entry Schengen Visa - Germany or Austria?

Tags: germany, schengen-visas, austria

I'm an Indian national, currently living in the UK on Tier 4 Student Visa (General). I've been to Schengen territory once and planning one more trip in coming months as below;

Austria 23rd December, 2018 till 31st December, 2018. (coming back to UK).
The Netherlands from 20th January, 2019 till 24th January, 2019.
Germany from 24th January, 2019 till 4th February, 2019.

In this particular case, where should I make an application? I'm going to spend maximum days in Germany; however, I'll be returning from Austria without entering Germany and then again going back to Schengen area for more days including The Netherlands and Germany.

I'd really appreciate your help.
Thank you!

Comment: What are the purposes of these trips? If the purposes point to a definite main destination, that trumps the "longest stay" fallback rule.

Comment: Close voters, this has nothing to do with [expatriates.se]. The fact that the asker has a long-term UK visa is irrelevant to the actual question. The question is about short-term Schengen visas. That is absolutely on-topic, here.

Answer (score 0):

As far as Schengen is concerned, you are planning two trips. The first is to Austria, the second is to the Netherlands and Germany. You **could** do that with two separate single-entry visa. Multiple-entry visa are usually granted for the convenience of the visitor and the visa officials *after* several problem-free single entries.

- Since your first trip is to Austria, you definitely have to apply for an Austrian Schengen visa.
- The time would be tight to apply for the second visa after the first trip, so you could mention both in the same application and hope for the best. If they grant you a visa with enough entries and duration/validity, you can use it on the subsequent trips.
- If not, for the second visa the "main destination" rule mentioned by Henning in his comment applies. You count days if there is no *specific* reason to go to one of the countries (e.g. a business meeting in the Netherlands, followed by some sightseeing in Germany).